# The convex hull of a precompact set in a Banach space is precompact

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

At the begining of the Chapter 21 of Peter Lax's functional analysis, he says that

If C is a precompact set in a Banach space, so is its convex hull.

can be deduced from the following properties:

(a) S is precompact if and only if every sequence of points of S contains a Cauchy subsequence.

(b) S is precompact iff for every $\epsilon >0 $ it can be covered by a finite number of balls of radius $\epsilon$.

I can not see how we can deduce it from these properties, can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $n_k$ be a finite $\epsilon$-net for $C$ and let $A= \operatorname{co} C$.

Then $N=\operatorname{co} \{n_k \}_k$ and note that $N$ is contained in a finite dimensional subspace and hence is compact. In particular, $N$ has a finite $\epsilon$-net $\nu_k$.

I claim that this is an $2\epsilon$-net for $A$.

If $x \in A$, then $x = \sum_i \lambda_i c_i$ with $\sum_i \lambda_i = 1$, $\lambda_i \ge 0$,  and $c_i \in C$.

Choose $n_{k_i}$ to be an element of $C$'s $\epsilon$-net nearest $c_i$, then
$n= \sum_k \lambda_i n_{k_i}$ satisfies $\|x-n\| < \epsilon$. Now choose $\nu_k$  such that $\|n-\nu_k\| < \epsilon$, then $\|x-\nu_k\| < 2 \epsilon$.

Comment: Didn't you mean to say that $N$ is only **pre**compact? We can conclude that $\overline{N} \subset \text{Span}((n_k)_{k = 1}^{\ell})$ is a closed and bounded subset of a finite dimensional subspace (then span) and therefore compact, implying the precompactness of $N$, right? This would also make sense in context because this would imply that $N$ is totally bounded and therefore contains a finite $\varepsilon$-net.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: Well, $N$ is compact. View it as the range of $\mu \mapsto \sum_k \mu_k n_k$ over the set $\{ \mu | \sum_k \mu_k = 1 , \mu_k \ge 0 \}$. Since the latter is compact, so is the range.

Comment: Also in the second last paragraph the summation over $i$ is a finite sum, right?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: Yes, all the sums are finite.

Comment: When saying $n := \sum_{k} \lambda_i n_{k_i}$, do you mean to actually sum over $i$?

Comment: But is my reasoning in my first comment correct and sufficient for the proof?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: Yes regarding the misnamed index. I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to show. $N$ is the convex hull of the finite $\epsilon$-net, so is compact, not just precompact.

Comment: @"I'm not sure I follow what you are trying to show." Since for your proof we only need the finite $\varepsilon$-cover of $N$, it would suffice to show that $N$ is precompact $=$ totally bounded, right? (Your argument showing that it is compact obviously implies it is also precompact) I tried to argue that in the my first comment that $N$ is precompact. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik: I see what you are saying. Yes, it will work, but you have compactness because of the finite dimensions in any case.